# How to observe if database content has changed

Tags: android, database, observer-pattern, android-contentprovider

I'm wondering how to observe if the underlying database tables of a Cursor have changed, so I could update the UI.

Are there any build in mechanisms? I've read about the [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) class but as far as I understand, they can only be used with [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) and not when the database is accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

we can do he same with oracle database.
But sqlite doesnot support stored procedure.
What you can do is that you can run a thread for database operation. Check the data in database always. whenver any change occurred in database. check for the database if size of database changes then you can call your application.

### How to call java program from db call

Call java program from oracle stored procedure.

Suppose there is oracle stored procedure OSP1 and a Java program Java1.
Now need to create a oracle stored procedure OSP2 on Java1.
Then we can simply call OSP2 from OSP1.

Steps in breif are:

1. Use loadjava (command line executable found in bin directory of where you installed oracle) to load the java class in oracle.
   $bin> loadjava -user scott/tiger Java1.class

The above class is now loaded in database and can be seen in dba_object view.

1. Now create an oracle stored procedure OSP2 built on Java1.class loaded in database.
   $bin> create or replace procedure OSP2 as language java
   name 'Java1.method1()';
   where method1() is a method in java class Java1.
2. Now OSP2 can be directly executed :
   execute OSP2;
   or called from dbms_java
   or can be called from another oracle stored procedure OSP1.

Comment: Thx for your answer but as you already mentioned SQLite don't support this and I'm looking for a solution for Android.

Comment: Hi Flo I think you have to write your own listener for that